# Budget tracker program not working in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to improve this program. I am working with Linux. I want to add a menu function where the user can pick an option and based on the option call the respective function, but the program is not working, when I run it in the Terminal it doesn't do anything and doesn't show any errors. Please, I need help to solve the problem and make the program works. Thanks!

Here's what I have so far, still there are some functions that need to develop:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys

def menu(self):
    print ("""
                1. Add an Expense
                2. Remove an Expense
                3. Add revenue
                4. Remove Revenue
                5. Exit
                """)
                
    option = input ("What would you like to do [Number Only]?")
    
    if option == "1":
        self.add_expense()
    elif option == "2":
        self.remove_expense()
    elif option == "3":
        self.add_revenue()
    elif option == "4":
        self.remove_revenue()
    else:
        self.reset_program()
        self.close_program()
    
    return option
        
def add_expense(self):

    def __init__(self):
        self.month_balance = 0
        self.expenses = 0
        self.expense_list = []
        self.expense_name = []
        self.month_balance_name = []
        self.month_balance_list = []
        self.prompt_income()
        
    def month_balance_ask(self):
        add_month_balance = input('Add monthly balance? [y/n]: ')
        return add_month_balance

    def month_balance_sum(self):
        self.month_balance = sum(self.month_balance_list)

    def expense_ask(self):
        add_expense = input('Add expense? [y/n]: ')
        return add_expense

    def expense_sum(self):
        self.expenses = sum(self.expense_list)

    def month_balance_check(self):
        if not self.month_balance_list:
            print('Please enter at least one monthly balance. ')
            self.prompt_month_balance()
    
    def expense_check(self):
        if not self.expense_list:
            print('Please enter at least one expense. ')
            self.prompt_expense()
            
    def prompt_month_balance(self):
        x = False
        while not x:
            result = self.month_balance_ask()
            if result == 'y':
                month_balance_input = int(input('Enter monthly balance. [Numbers Only]: '))
                self.month_balance_list.append(month_balance_input)
                month_balance_name = input('Enter monthly balance name. [Name Only]: ')
                self.month_balance_name.append(month_balance_name)
            else:
                self.month_balance_check()
                x = True
        self.month_balance_sum()
        name = [name for name in self.month_balance_name]
        month_balance = [month_balance for month_balance in self.month_balance_list]
        month_balancedict = dict(zip(name, month_balance))
        for k in incomedict:
            print(k + ': ', '$' + str(month_balancedict[k]))
        print('Total user monthly balance: ', '$' + str(self.month_balance))
        self.prompt_expense()
        
    def prompt_expense(self):
        x = False
        while not x:
            result = self.expense_ask()
            if result == 'y':
                expense_input = int(input('Enter expense amount. [Numbers Only]: '))
                self.expense_list.append(expense_input)
                expense_name = input('Enter expense name. [Name Only]: ')
                self.expense_name.append(expense_name)
            else:
                self.expense_check()
                x = True
        self.expense_sum()
        name = [name for name in self.expense_name]
        expense = [income for income in self.expense_list]
        expensedict = dict(zip(name, expense))
        for k in expensedict:
            print(k + ': ', '$' + str(expensedict[k]))
        print('Total user expenses: ', '$' + str(self.expenses))
        self.added_expense()
        
    def added_expense(self):
        expenseadded = self.month_balance - self.expenses
        if expenseadded < 0:
            print('You are in the negative, you have a deficit of ' + '$' + str(expenseadded))
        if expenseadded == 0:
            print('You have broken even, you are spending exactly as much as you make.')
        if expenseadded > 0:
            print('You are in the positive, you have a surplus of ' + '$' + str(expenseadded))
        
        another = input('Would you like to run another analysis? [y/n]: ')
        if another == 'y':
            self.menu()
        else:
            self.reset_program()
            self.close_program()
            
def remove_expense(self):
    print("code goes here")
    
def add_revenue(self):
    print("code goes here")

def remove_revenue(self):
    print("code goes here")
            
def reset_program(self):
    self.month_balance = 0
    self.expenses = 0
    del self.expense_list[0:]
    del self.expense_name[0:]
    del self.month_balance_name[0:]
    del self.month_balance_list[0:]
    self.prompt_month_balance()

def close_program(self):
    print('Exiting Program.')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You've defined a bunch of functions but you aren't calling any of them. Do you mean to call `menu()` at the end of this?

Comment: Note that you don't need (and generally shouldn't include) `self` when defining standalone functions. That is for methods of classes, where the instance is passed in as the first argument to the method. And your `def add_expense()` looks like it's trying to _be_ a class? You can nest functions in Python, but you normally wouldn't nest an `__init__()` inside another function.

Comment: Please attempt to reduce it to the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem, and make sure to include the full error traceback

Comment: Yes Chris, I mean to call menu() at the end of add_expense() if the user would like to do another analysis.

Comment: @L3ly, that's for _another_ analysis. What about the first one?

Comment: I want the menu() to be shown at the beginning of the program, then the user picks an option and based on the option, runs the specific function. and call menu() at the end of the other functions as remove_expense(), add_revenue() and remove_revenue()